# Unable to convert fully a function based form view to a class based form view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to convert the following function based view to a Class based view:

(Essentially after the form is submitted validly or invalidly, the user is redirected to the same page again).

Old Code:

```
def handle_form(request, template_name='contact.html'):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            do_something()
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

New Code:

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contact')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        do_something()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The subtle difference in the new code is that if the form is valid, the submitted values of the form are forgotten. The behaviour in the old code was that the values are always remembered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormView implements a standard flow for a form, which is to not re-display the populated form after successfully saving it.

To do what you want, you would have to do the form save yourself and then render the view again with the context passed to it, instead of relying on the super-class method to do it.

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        do_something()
        form.save()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I realised after reading the code for FormView class.

Answer (score 0):

form_valid will perform a redirect, not render the template. You'll need to ditch the default behavior and render the template like you normally would (I assume you're not saving a model, otherwise you should simply redirect to the url